# Typescript create an object based on interface name?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have couple of interface that I would like to create a object with the same key as interface, how can I do that?

```
export interface First {
  first: string;
}
export interface Last {
  last: string;
}
export interface Gender {
  gender: boolean;
}
#I would like to have any result as following
const obj = {
  first: 'first'
  last: 'last'
  gender: true,
}
```

Comment: You are trying to have a class implement multiple interfaces?

Comment: When you say "result", do you mean you want a function that outputs this object, or just a type declaration for it?

Answer (score 2):

You can define an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) like so:

```
type Thing = First & Last & Gender

const obj: Thing = {
    first: 'a',
    last: 'b',
    gender: false
}
```

Comment: Since I already have interface can I do something so object will have exactly key name like all interface? Because if I have more than 40 item like first key. I do not want to list them out and assign value one by one?

Comment: @jacobcan118 What do you mean "exactly key name like all interface"?  You think the compiler should create the intersection of a bunch of interfaces without you having to mention those interfaces?  "All interfaces defined in my code" isn't something the compiler will understand.  Maybe you should just create your interface like `interface All {first: string, last: string, gender: boolean}` and then later refer to `Pick<All, "first">` or `Pick<All, "gender">` instead of declaring the `First` or `Gender` etc interfaces.

Answer (score -1):

HI you need to add the variable type interface

```
first: First;
last: Last;
gender:Gender;

export class AppComponent{
obj = {
  first: this.first,
  last: this.last,
  gender: this.gender,
}
}
```

I hope this help you
Regards